# Element shown as text in Tooltipster (tooltipster.js)

Tags: tooltipster

I am using Tooltipster.js to apply a fancy tooltip. The problem is that when I set a text in the tooltip, it gets rendered as it is, which I don't want. I want it to show as a rendered html.

E.g.

This is my code:

```
var total = "<p><strong>text</strong></p>";

$(this).tooltipster({
    content: total,
    multiple: true
});
```

Now, the tooltip shows it to me as `<p><strong>text</strong></p>`. I want it to look as **text**.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

I have to add `contentAsHTML: true`.

Looked at other help in Stackoverflow.